# aiogram bot. Как в машине состояний принимать текст до тех пор, пока не будет введено нужное количество слов?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Есть бот на aiogram, который принимает заказы. Я использую машину состояний, и мне нужно, чтобы бот мог фильтровать введенное пользователем тз, то есть если слов меньше 10, то тз считается коротким и нужно расписать его подробнее

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Form.order)
async def ordering(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):

    global o
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        ordr = message.text
        
        if 'Обратно в меню' in ordr:
            await message.answer('Меню', reply_markup=kb.inline_kb_full)
            await Form.next()

        elif len(ordr.split()) < 10:
            await message.answer('Слишком короткое тз, распишите подробнее')
            await Form.order.set()

        elif len(ordr.split()) >= 10:
            ind = len(o) + 1
            o.append([ind, ordr])
            await message.answer('Ваш заказ принят. Ожидайте, в ближайшее время с вами свяжутся', reply_markup=kb.inline_kb_full)
    await Form.next()
```

я попытался сделать это следующим образом: если слов < 10, то заново сделать

```
await Form.order.set()
```

однако это не работает, потому что если сначала ввести слов < 10, а потом больше, то бот просто не отвечает. Как это можно пофиксить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Form.order)
async def ordering(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    # собственно забудьте про глобальные переменные. Юзайте стейт дату.
    # которая у вас открыта но вы её игнорите
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        ordr = message.text

        if 'Обратно в меню' in ordr:
            await message.answer('Меню', reply_markup=kb.inline_kb_full)
            await Form.next()

        elif len(ordr.split()) < 10:
            await message.answer('Слишком короткое тз, распишите подробнее')
            # просто оставьте текущий стейт, смысл его менять?
            # await Form.order.set()
        elif len(ordr.split()) >= 10:
            # вот так записывайте в стейт
            # не уверен для чего вам номер заказа, но я лично не вижу особого смысла
            # у вас у каждого юзера своя data, потому вы не ошибетесь открыв его у него
            data['order'] = ordr
            await message.answer('Ваш заказ принят. Ожидайте, в ближайшее время с вами свяжутся',
                                 reply_markup=kb.inline_kb_full)
            # только если условие выполнено меняйте стейт
            await Form.next()
```

PS. Очень важно помнить что при `state.finish()` данные будут утеряны. Потому учитывайте это

Comment: Супер, спасибо большое, работает